# Find initial state such that $\frac{dP(t)}{dt} = - \ln(3) P(t) \left(1 - \frac{P(t)}{3}\right)$ doesn't exceed $4$ by $t = 4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $P(t)$ represent the amount of chemical a factory produces as a function of time $t$ in hours.
The rate of change of chemical production satisfies the differential
$$
\frac{dP(t)}{dt}
= - \ln(3) P(t) \left(1 - \frac{P(t)}{3}\right).
$$
If the factory alarm is raised when the chemical productions exceeds 4 in 4 hours, the inequality that represents the maximum initial amount of chemical that guarantees the alarm will not be raised is

1. $P(0) < \frac{108}{37}$.
2. $P(0) < \frac{108}{373}$.
3. $P(0) < \frac{972}{337}$.
4. $P(0) < \frac{972}{323}$.

4 is the right answer.

Comment: What does exceeds 4 in 4 hours meant? Do you want to know that too?

Comment: To ensure that there are no negative votes, it is sufficient to show the work in an attempt to solve the question.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please edit your post to show your efforts.

Comment: Hint: The solution of your equation is given by $$P(t)=\frac{3}{e^{3 c_1+t \log (3)}+1}$$

Comment: It's a standard [logistic equation.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html)

Comment: This answer is wrong, isn't it? The equation blows up at finite time if $P(0) > 3$, and $972/323 > 3$.

Comment: Please enter critical parts  of your question—in this case the entire question—as text instead of pasting a picture of it. Your question should be comprehensible with images disabled. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. Use MathJax to format mathematical expressions; you can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I don't have enough time to type again coz I am preparing for a test, moreover, I dunno how to type complex equations using Latex. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: My doubt is cleared!, So I request people to try this one instead!
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260864/problem-on-theory-of-equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODE solution is

$$
P(t) = \frac{3}{1+3^t e^{3C_0}}
$$

now we have

$$
P(4) = 4\Rightarrow C_0 = -\frac{\ln 324}{3}
$$

so after substituting $C_0$ we have

$$
P(0) = \frac{972}{323}
$$

[image]